# Hiking Bryce/Zion/Moab in mid-June

Tags: usa, weather-and-climate, hiking

I want to visit Bryce+Zion+Moab in mid-June. Is it a good time in terms of:

1. weather
2. crowd
3. availability of trails (e.g. open but not too much water in trails)

Answer (score 4):

1. Weather: The hot season for Zion and Moab begins in May.  By June, you can expect daily highs in the mid-90s F (30 C) and overnight lows around 60 F (15 C).  Bryce is at a much higher elevation, so high temperatures will typically be around 75 F (23 C) and overnight lows around 45 F (7 C).  In all three locations, you can expect dry weather and cloudless skies.
2. Crowd: Almost all schools are out for the summer.  You can expect large crowds of people in all three locations.
3. Trail availability: South Utah is desert.  You can expect the trails to be open and dry.

Is it a good time to visit?  Only you can answer that.

Comment: Mark is exactly right. I'll note that in terms of hiking, all but the most popular trails will not be crowded after about 1 km, but be sure you bring the proper supplies (water!). Also, be sure to check the national park service for warnings, trail conditions, etc. (here is Zion - http://www.nps.gov/zion/index.htm). Don't let heat and people prevent you from seeing these wonderful sites!

Answer (score 1):

Weather:

- As Mark had said, it can get very hot in Zion and Canyonlands and Arches (Moab area parks).  Get an early start to your day. The light is spectacular on the red rocks early in the morning.

Crowds

- Most visitors never go much farther than a few feet from the parking
  lot. Ask a ranger at the visitor center for recommendations on less crowded trails.
- Go to less visited but equally scenic sections of the parks - Kolub
  Canyon in Zion, Needles section of Canyonlands or Dead Horse State
  Park, etc. The Fiery Furnace in Arches is only accessible on a ranger
  walk or with a permit. Not going to be crowded.

Trail availability

- Trails should all be open but it is always a good idea to ask a ranger at the visitor center for recommendations on difficulty etc.

Other suggestions:

- Check the visitor center for the schedule of ranger walks and hikes. They are free and usually excellent.
- Take a jet boat tour of the Colorado River from Moab.